# How to become a supervisor? Finding students to supervise

Tags: collaboration, independent-researcher, supervision

I'm currently finishing the corrections of the PhD I've done in the UK. In the meantime, I've returned to my home country, Portugal, and started working at a hospital as a medical statistician. I have several (no scientific tasks) to do and I would like to continue doing research. I have several projects that I would like to carry one. Some are not very complicated and I believe they could be interesting master degree thesis. While in the UK, I've supervised some undergrads and I really enjoyed. I would like to continue supervising students.

Does anyone have any experience or guidance about how could I start to supervise research students (proposing small projects)? I don't need to be affiliated with a university to be a supervisor as my master thesis supervisor was not a teacher there. But, do I need to be affiliated with a university to propose projects? I imagine I can only be a supervisor in Portugal or has anyone heard about master degree supervisors from other countries? I understand this may differ between countries. I'm looking for some tips/advice/comments on how to start supervising students.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any contacts at local universities? You will need some university to be involved.

Comment: I'm still in touch with one or two teachers at the university where I did my masters. I'm thinking about reaching them. Not sure how to proceed with other universities or if I should keep the collaboration with only one university.

Comment: @pavid yes, you can also contact private one, good thing is that statistics are valuble in all fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the possible approaches in which you can get people (especially students) to know you. Since, you are in a hospital working as a statistician it would be more valuable and increase the chance of getting students.

1. **Deliver talks at local organisations/universities:** You should try to meet the head and principal of the university. Discuss with them your profile and eager to talk to the students. If your talk is well accepted by the students, some of those students would surely be interested to work with you. Moreover, professors would also like to collaborate with you.
2. **Visit conferences and present your works:** Work on your own and write research papers, visit the conferences or seminars. There you will get to know few aspiring students and people to work with.
3. **Discussion with your own colleagues in the hospital:** I am sure you may not be alone and wanting to work on research. There will always be someone. Since, you are new; talk to your colleagues and propose your ideas to work on it. This will help you get the above points (1) and (2) easily.

Comment: Thank you! I've already started one collaboration at the hospital but I need to be more proactive once I finish the corrections. The first point is a good idea. Collaborating with professors would also be interesting.